# Wordpress Site content messed up, could not login to admin

Tags: wordpress

I have this site running completely fine http://theweddingcompany.com.sg
Then all of a sudden we could not login to the admin panel, giving us the error invalid username and password. 
None of us changed the password.

I would like to decrypt the password from database if possible, to check if it's still the same as previously but I tried many MD5 decrypter but they could not decrypt the password.
Anyone has any idea how to decrypt the password?

Anyone had this issue before? The contents are messed up as well, line breaks went missing, some plugins break.

Thanks for your input!

EDITED : I have reset the password using "Forget Password" link , but could not login using the new password... what could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the issue before. Before I tell you what I did, can I ask why you aren't using the password recovery feature to have it emailed to the admin email address? Despite that question, I've not only lost a password but also forgotten what the info for the admin email was.

Anyways, I had issues decrypting the MD5 as well (I believe I once read a reason, but don't recall it). What did work was just adding a brand new password via a [MD5 generator](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php) and the phpMyAdmin panel.

If you don't have access to phpMyAdmin, then wordpress offers a number of other solutions here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Good luck, I know it can be a pain! BTW, nice looking site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The reason why I wanted to retrieve the password from the database coz I wanna checked if the password has been changed. We remember our password, so wondering if someone hacked into the site? hahah but there's nothing on the site for them to take :p